# I've got the following code to randomly create a string of letters, but it makes some of them capitalised

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need the random string to be in lowercase - I tried a.lower(), but couldn't get it to work.

```
def random_char(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for x in range(y))
```

I'm a complete novice, so clear and simple answers please, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you pick from only characters you want in the output, then?

Comment: have you tried `string.letters.lower()` ?

Comment: (string.letters.lower()) has worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to

```
def random_char(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(y))
```

(docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lowercase)

Comment: I also found the following worked: def random_char(y): return ''.join(random.choice(string.letters.lower()) for x in range(y))

Answer (score 1):

`string.letters` has too much stuff in it... but `string.ascii_lowercase` is right, so use it

```
>>> import string
>>> string.letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> import random
>>> ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(10))
'rathkzncdj'
>>>
```

As an aside, `random.sample` does the loop for you

```
>>> ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 10))
'hbegfsinqt'
>>>
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye - yep . figured that out while you were typing and changed it! thanks.